# Defining HTML template in Backbone.js using Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am currently converting a javascript backbone.js view into coffeescript but it isn't working correctly.

My working original Javascript view is

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/dashboard/main.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, mainHomeTemplate){

  var Test = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    render: function(){
      this.$el.html(mainHomeTemplate);
    }
  });
  return Test;
});
```

My coffeescript view is

```
define [
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/dashboard/main.html'
], ($, _, Backbone, mainHomeTemplate) ->

Test = Backbone.View.extend
    el: $ '#page'

    render: ->
        $(@el).html @mainHomeTemplate

Test
```

When I try to initialize the test view I get it says that Test is undefined.

```
app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) {
      require(['views/dashboard/testnew'], function(Test) {
        console.log(Test)
        var test = new Test();
        test.render();
       });
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referencing `mainHomeTemplate` as an instance variable (`@mainHomeTemplate`, the same thing as `this.mainHomeTemplate`) when it just just a plain local variable. You want:

```
Test = Backbone.View.extend
    el: $ '#page'

    render: ->
        $(@el).html mainHomeTemplate # <-------- No '@' on 'mainHomeTemplate'
```

And while I'm here, you should let Backbone take care of jQuery stuff for `el` and your view already has [`@$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) (assuming that you're using a recent version of Backbone) so you don't have to `$(@el)`:

```
Test = Backbone.View.extend
    el: '#page'
    render: ->
        @$el.html mainHomeTemplate
```

I'm assuming that the lack of indentation in your `define` function is just a copy/paste error as well; you have to be very careful with your indentation in CoffeeScript, doubly so when pasting CoffeeScript code into a question. You can also use the normal CoffeeScript class mechanism instead of `Backbone.View.extend`. Your final result should look something like this:

```
define [
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/dashboard/main.html'
], ($, _, Backbone, mainHomeTemplate) ->

    class Test extends Backbone.View
        el: '#page'

        render: ->
            @$el.html mainHomeTemplate

    Test
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You were spot on, gave a good explanation and helped me improve the rest of my code. Thanks.